# Error using Rest plugin in cakephp

Tags: rest, cakephp, controller

I'm implementing web service in cakephp.

I found a plugin [here](https://github.com/kvz/cakephp-rest-plugin) to do this. When I do the installation steps, any trial to access controller/action.json request I get this error:

```
Strict (2048): Declaration of RestComponent::initialize() 
should be compatible with Component::initialize(Controller $controller)
```

What does it mean that it should be compatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class methods that override methods of a parent class should implement the same signatures as the methods that are being overwritten, ie the `intialize` method in the `RestComponent` should look like this ([https://github.com/cakephp/.../Component.php#L109](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component.php#L109)):

```
public function initialize(Controller $controller)
```

instead of this ([https://github.com/kvz/cakephp-rest-plugin/...RestComponent.php#L153](https://github.com/kvz/cakephp-rest-plugin/blob/master/Controller/Component/RestComponent.php#L153)):

```
public function initialize(&$Controller)
```

Comment: so it is a bug in the plugin itself ? should I modify this ?

Comment: I'd suggest so... also it would be a good idea to notify the plugin author so that he can fix it in his repository.

Answer (score 0):

[CakePHP has a REST API built into it](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html), unless you're doing something that hasn't been done already.

Answer (score 0):

use this

public function initialize(Controller $controller)